# lateinit property mClickListener has not been initialized Adapter kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, lateinit

i make adaper onclick listener but somehow theres error message  lateinit property mClickListener has not been initialized Adapter kotlin

variable on click

```
lateinit var mClickListener: ItemClickListener
```

base view holder

```
inner class AdapterListProjectVH2(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder(itemView),
        View.OnClickListener {
        private val cvItemViewVisualInsp: CardView =
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_itemview_visual_insp)
        private val imgMarkOnMap: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_mark_on_map)
        private val imgStatusSync: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_status_sync)
        //private val imgStatusRegister : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_status_register)

        private val tvFootpathTypeName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_foot_type_name)
        private val tvSeverityTypeName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_severity_type)
        private val tvRepairMethodName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_repair_method_name)
        private val tvRfCreatedDate: TextView =
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rf_created_date)
        private val clInspected: ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cl_inspected)

        private val imageSlider: SliderView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider)

        init {
            cvItemViewVisualInsp.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
```

overide click function

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            mClickListener.onClickItem(adapterPosition, itemView, mData?.get(adapterPosition))
        }
 fun setOnItemClickListener(clickListener: ItemClickListener) {
        mClickListener = clickListener
    }

    fun clear() {
        this.mData!!.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    interface ItemClickListener {
        fun onClickItem(
            pos: Int,
            aView: View,
            data: ViewFootpathEntityWIthAllData?
        )
    }
```

Activity call onclick listerner

```
  footPathadapter = FootpathAdapter(this, footPathDataList)
        footPathadapter?.setOnItemClickListener(object : FootpathAdapter.ItemClickListener{
            override fun onClickItem(pos: Int, aView: View, data: ViewFootpathEntityWIthAllData?) {
                startActivity(Intent(this@FormFootpathActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
            }
        })
```

Comment: That error means you tried to use your `lateinit var` object somewhere before setting it. You would need to post a more complete picture of where these methods are and where they are called to say exactly why. I can't tell if `mClickListener` is in the ViewHolder or the adapter, and I can't tell where your methods like `setOnItemClickListener` are located (in the adapter?). The error message in the Logcat should tell you where the error comes from though (what line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the Adapter instance before passing `mClickListener`, when you create the adapter an instance of `AdapterListProjectVH2` is going to be created and the this code is going to be executed:

```
    init {
        cvItemViewVisualInsp.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
```

Which will cose the error because this cause is going to be executed before you set the `mClickListener`.

So you can initialize `mClickListener` as null like that:

```
var mClickListener: ItemClickListener? = null
```

And add a null check when call it like that:

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    mClickListener?.onClickItem(adapterPosition, itemView, mData?.get(adapterPosition))
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer , but when i do the step you give, when i click the item it doesn't have a respon

Answer (score 0):

I solve by my self, it because i put the code in wrong activity

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).